# Position Google Maps with sidebar on right and fixed header on top

Tags: css

I'm looking to position a Google Maps div with a sidebar on the right that displays listings. I want to make it so the window doesn't scroll, and the contents on the page are fluid when resizing the screen.

I have previously attempted to use box-sizing like the following:

```
    #map-wrapper * {
     box-sizing: border-box !important;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
     -khtml-box-sizing: border-box !important;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    }
    #map-container {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%; height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     border-top: 50px solid transparent !important; border-right: 350px solid transparent !important;
    }
```

This starts to become a nightmare when trying to have a scrolling list in the sidebar. Does anyone have a good solution, or am I on the right track with box-sizing?

Comment: This is a CSS question. Nothing to do with maps.

Answer (score 0):

Box-sizing is purely optional for something like this. There are many ways to go about it, but I have one favored method that is simple and works well in old browsers like IE6.

For the various frames you are trying to create (sidebar and Gmaps/content frame) create a css rule that sets `position:absolute; overflow:auto;`. Now you can take advantage of a cool trick in CSS absolute positioning. If you set both `top` and `bottom` in CSS, the height is automatically calculated. Same goes for widths using left/right. So to make our two divs 100% height set `top: 0; bottom:0;`.

If you want the sidebar to be 300px wide and anchored to the right, then set `width:300px; right:0;`. For the content div, set `right:300px; left:0;`.

Now you need to prevent the body scrollbars from appearing. First of all, you will need to remove the default margin/padding from body by setting them to 0. Also, you need to set html & body to `height:100%;` (100% equals the viewing area height), other wise they default to `auto` which is the content's height. It is also wise to add `overflow:hidden` to body, since some browsers think `body{height:100%;} means they need to show scrollbars.

[Here is a quick mockup on JS fiddle showing you how this works.](http://jsfiddle.net/kuXYq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Elimn's suggestion did not work for me, but the following did (I created a header bar above the Google Map):

```
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#map-canvas { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

In the body:

```
<div id="topmenubar" style="position:relative;background:olive;height:40px;top:0;"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```